"pcl::KdTreeFLANN" is extremely slow
I am using ROS2-Iron on Ubuntu 22.04 to filter points in a LiDAR point cloud from a rosbag, based on the following criteria: (1) points with intensity values below a certain threshold, and (2) points with fewer neighbors than a specified minimum number. To count the neighbors within a given radius, I am using the pcl::KdTreeFLANN library. However, when visualizing the results in RViz2, the performance is extremely slow. If I increase the radius or the minimum neighbor count for KdTreeFLANN, the point cloud filter processing becomes unresponsive. I would like to avoid downsampling the point cloud. Are there alternative methods to speed up this filtering process?
Original code:
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;


class KdTreeFilterNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    KdTreeFilterNode() : Node("kdtree_filter_node")
    {
        this->declare_parameter<std::string>("kdtree/inputTopic", "/ouster_front/points");
        this->declare_parameter<double>("kdtree/radius_search",50.0);//mm 
        this->declare_parameter<int>("kdtree/minNeighbours", 3);
        this->declare_parameter<double>("intensity_threshold", 100.0);

        this->get_parameter("kdtree/inputTopic", input_topic_);
        this->get_parameter("kdtree/radius_search", radius_);
        this->get_parameter("kdtree/minNeighbours", min_neighbours_);
        this->get_parameter("intensity_threshold", intensity_threshold_);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "The input topic is: %s", input_topic_.c_str());
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Radius search is set to: %.2f", radius_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Minimum neighbors required: %d", min_neighbours_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Intensity threshold: %.2f", intensity_threshold_);

        sub_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
            input_topic_, rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(),
            std::bind(&KdTreeFilterNode::cloud_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1));

        pub_output_points_ = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("kdtree/output", 10);
    }

private:
    void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr cloud_msg)
    {
        // Convert ROS msg to PCL data type
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>());
        pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud_msg, *cloud);

        // KDTree for neighbor search
        pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZI> kdtree;
        kdtree.setInputCloud(cloud);
        //kdtree.setEpsilon(0.1);  // Set the epsilon for approximate nearest neighbor search


        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>());
        std::vector<int> point_idx_radius_search;
        std::vector<float> point_radius_squared_distance;

        // Iterate over all points in the cloud
        for (const auto& point : cloud->points)
        {
            // Perform radius search to find neighbors within the specified radius
            int neighbors_count = kdtree.radiusSearch(point, radius_, point_idx_radius_search, point_radius_squared_distance);

            // Apply the filter condition
            if (!(point.intensity <= intensity_threshold_ && neighbors_count < min_neighbours_))
            {
                // Keep points that do not meet the removal condition
                cloud_filtered->points.push_back(point);
            }
        }

        cloud_filtered->width = cloud_filtered->points.size();
        cloud_filtered->height = 1;
        cloud_filtered->is_dense = true;

        // Convert the filtered PCL data back to ROS message
        sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 output;
        pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_filtered, output);
        output.header = cloud_msg->header;

        // Publish the filtered point cloud
        pub_output_points_->publish(output);
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr sub_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr pub_output_points_;
    std::string input_topic_;
    double radius_;
    int min_neighbours_;
    double intensity_threshold_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<KdTreeFilterNode>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

Modified code:
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h> // Include OpenMP for parallel processing
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class KdTreeFilterNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    KdTreeFilterNode() : Node("kdtree_filter_node")
    {
        this->declare_parameter<std::string>("kdtree/inputTopic", "/ouster_front/points");
        this->declare_parameter<double>("kdtree/radius_search",50.0);//mm 
        this->declare_parameter<int>("kdtree/minNeighbours", 3);
        this->declare_parameter<double>("intensity_threshold", 150.0);

        this->get_parameter("kdtree/inputTopic", input_topic_);
        this->get_parameter("kdtree/radius_search", radius_);
        this->get_parameter("kdtree/minNeighbours", min_neighbours_);
        this->get_parameter("intensity_threshold", intensity_threshold_);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "The input topic is: %s", input_topic_.c_str());
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Radius search is set to: %.2f", radius_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Minimum neighbors required: %d", min_neighbours_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Intensity threshold: %.2f", intensity_threshold_);

        sub_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
            input_topic_, rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(),
            std::bind(&KdTreeFilterNode::cloud_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1));

        pub_output_points_ = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("kdtree/output", 10);
    }

private:
    void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr cloud_msg)
    {
        // Convert ROS msg to PCL data type
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>());
        pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud_msg, *cloud);

        // KDTree for neighbor search
        pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZI> kdtree;
        kdtree.setInputCloud(cloud);
        //kdtree.setEpsilon(0.1);  // Set the epsilon for approximate nearest neighbor search


        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>());
        std::vector<int> point_idx_radius_search;
        std::vector<float> point_radius_squared_distance;

        // Initialize the keep_point vector
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> keep_point(cloud->size(), 0);

        // Parallel loop using OpenMP
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) schedule(dynamic, 32) shared(keep_point, kdtree)
        for (int i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); ++i)
        {
            const auto& point = cloud->points[i];

            // Check the intensity condition
            if (point.intensity > intensity_threshold_)
            {
                keep_point[i] = 1; // Mark the point to keep
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform radius search to find neighbors within the specified radius
                int neighbors_count = kdtree.radiusSearch(point, radius_, point_idx_radius_search, point_radius_squared_distance, min_neighbours_);
                if (neighbors_count >= min_neighbours_)
                {
                    keep_point[i] = 1; // Mark the point to keep
                }
            }
        }

        // Iterate over keep_point vector and add points to cloud_filtered
        for (int i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (keep_point[i])
            {
                cloud_filtered->points.push_back(cloud->points[i]);
            }
        }


        cloud_filtered->width = cloud_filtered->points.size();
        cloud_filtered->height = 1;
        cloud_filtered->is_dense = true;

        // Convert the filtered PCL data back to ROS message
        sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 output;
        pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_filtered, output);
        output.header = cloud_msg->header;

        // Publish the filtered point cloud
        pub_output_points_->publish(output);
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr sub_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr pub_output_points_;
    std::string input_topic_;
    double radius_;
    int min_neighbours_;
    double intensity_threshold_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<KdTreeFilterNode>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

I appreciate any help in advance.
Thanks,
Abbas

A few things: PCL has RadiusOutlierRemoval and StatisticalOutlierRemoval filters. Have you tried those? They may be faster. Second, I would suggest to first filter by intensity, then (on the remaining points) by neighbours. Then you save some costly neighbourhood searches. Third, PCL has an OrganizedNeighbour search which is much faster but only works on specific datasets (e.g. like from a depth image). Fourth, what is the exact set-up? Does the shown code run in a separate node and publish the filtered cloud? How many messages per second does the shown code receive?

@IBitMyBytes Thank you for your prompt response. I am familiar with those outlier removal methods, but both conditions need to be met simultaneously; otherwise, many inlier points might be removed due to their low intensity values. The setup consists of a node that subscribes to point cloud data, processes it, and publishes the filtered output. On average, the node receives around 2 messages per second.

@IBitMyBytes Thank you for your helpful suggestions. I have edited my original code (just cloud_cb function) and have uploaded the modified code on my original question above based on your suggestions (except OrganizedNeighbor). The outlier filtering process became a little bit faster, but still very very slow. Can you please let me know whether I correctly modified my code or not?

@IBitMyBytes  Also when I used OrganizedNeighbor or  radius_outlier_removal libraries for outliers removal, I got this message Input dataset is not from a projective device!, and I think it shows my pointcloud data is not organized and projective file.

Yes, the modifications look correct. Make sure that OpenMP is indeed used by commenting out the #pragma line and checking if the code runs slower than before. If the code is not parallel, you have to activate OpenMP in the CMakeLists.txt. How long does one run of cloud_cb take? It probably also makes sense to profile your code, to find out where exactly your program spends the most time. Valgrind's callgrind is one option for this. And another thing: make sure to set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to RelWithDebInfo or Release, so that the compiler optimizes properly.

@IBitMyBytes Thank you for reviewing my code and your helpful suggestions. I will apply your recommendations and find out their effects on the code performance.

In your comment you say that the node should be able to process 2 messages per second, so 500 milliseconds per message. Whether this is doable or not depends on your computer and the number of points, but here are some tips that might help you achieve that:
Avoid neighbourhood search if possible
From your code above, you want to keep a point if the following condition is met:
!(point.intensity <= intensity_threshold_ && neighbors_count < min_neighbours_). This is the same as point.intensity > intensity_threshold_ || neighbors_count >= min_neighbours_. This means that you can (sometimes) avoid the costly neighbourhood search like this:
if (point.intensity > intensity_threshold_) {
  // keep point: add to cloud_filtered
}
else {
  int neighbors_count = kdtree.radiusSearch(point, radius_, point_idx_radius_search, point_radius_squared_distance);
  if (neighbors_count >= min_neighbours_) {
    // keep point: add to cloud_filtered
  }
}

Make neighbourhood search faster
You do not need to know the exact number of neighbours of each point, you only need to know whether there are at least min_neighbours_ neighbours. By adding an additional parameter to radiusSearch, you can tell it to stop searching if enough neighbours are found: kdtree.radiusSearch(point, radius_, point_idx_radius_search, point_radius_squared_distance, min_neighbours_); See also https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_kd_tree_f_l_a_n_n.html#a9b2485acd008ac09559a95820592782e
OrganizedNeighbor
I already mentioned this in my comment but wanted to mentioned it here again: PCL has a search class called OrganizedNeighbor which is much faster than the KdTreeFLANN. It only works on specific point clouds (organized and projectable). Not sure if your data is suitable for this algorithm, but if you check width and height of your point clouds and both are larger than one, then there is a good chance that OrganizedNeighbor will work.
Parallelize
Using OpenMP to parallelize your code is not very difficult and can speed it up a lot. Here is an idea in pseudocode:
std::vector<std::uint8_t> keep_point(cloud->size(), 0);
// Iterate of all points in parallel
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) schedule(dynamic, 32) shared(keep_point, kdtree)
for(int i=0; i<cloud->size(); ++i) {
  // check if point should be kept, if yes, write keep_point[i]=1;
}
// Iterate again, but not parallel
for(int i=0; i<cloud->size(); ++i) {
  if(keep_point[i]) {
    cloud_filtered->points.push_back(point);
  }
}

This solution with the keep_point vector avoids mutex locks in the parallel loop (adding points to cloud_filtered would have to be protected by a mutex lock if done in a parallel loop).
